# customizing Tapku Calendar for iPad resolutions

Tags: ios, ipad, tapku

I want to customize the Tapku Calander so that it fits the complete iPad screen.

Can any one please guide me through the methods in which I need to make changes to the coordinates so that it fits the screen well enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (appDelegate.isIpad)
{
    calendar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
}
else
{
    calendar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}

// Ensure this is the last "addSubview" because the calendar must be the top most view layer    
[self.view addSubview:calendar];
```

Use CGAffineTransformMakeScale before `addSubview:` and you will get iPad kind of resolution.